# Accessing google one drive on website server side

Tags: php, forms, google-docs, onedrive

I am trying to connect to google one drive on my website using php to upload submitted form information.

Client side: User fills form, submits form, goes to success page.

Website side: receives data, connects to one drive account using a predetermined user account, information is uploaded, user is redirected.

I am trying to avoid the client being asked to sign in, or do be able to have any access to the google docs files or user.

how would I do this? I saw a way to do it using Zend GData but from what I could tell you need to have access to a console. My host does not allow me to install anything.

I have tried to connect using some api code, but the requests were done through url to connect the user to one drive with their google account.

I have looked into this for the last 5 hours and just keep coming back confused. Could use some help because there is too much information for me to get a good footing on what I need to do.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Microsoft OneDrive or Google Drive? It's unclear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer. I didnt have enough rep to comment or ask a question.**
Did you mean the predetermined account belonging to the user or yours? 
If its your account and you were referring to the google page while is it being authenticated, it shouldnt happen if you provide the auth code before hand to your script.

http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001954.html

The above URL has a similar piece of code where it was mentioned that such a page would be seen for the first time. Is that what your question is about?

Comment: Predetermined account belonging to me. In fact I wanted to be the owner of both accounts. It's like sending an email from a website using my email, to send to the another email when some one fills a form. I own both emails and they never know an email is being sent.

Yes my question was about that

Comment: But I am able to use google log in to ask them but I am concerned that if I do that to alter the spreadsheet file, it will either have to be a public file. or they are able to read the file (list of peoples contact info)

Comment: The files in google drive are private by default until you share them. And it would be a file upload from your server to Google Drive. Are you saying you are seeing the auth screen after you provided the auth code?